# Passing new object as default argument to constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments, default-value

I have a constructor which looks like:

```
RandomClass(const int16_t var1, const SecondClass& var2);
```

I need to pass a default argument to the second parameter, so currently I do something like this:

```
RandomClass(const int16_t var1, const SecondClass& var2 = *(new SecondClass(*(new std::unordered_map<int16_t, double>())));
```

which is incredibly awkward. Note that I do not want to use an overloaded constructor, or change the second parameter from a reference to a pointer.

What would an elegant way of passing the default parameter be?

Comment: The elegant way would involve using 2 overloads rather than defaulting.

Comment: Not only is your current method not elegant, it creates a memory leak - those `new`s are not paired with `delete`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allowed to bind a const reference to a temporary:

```
RandomClass(const int16_t var1, const SecondClass& var2 = SecondClass(std::unordered_map<int16_t, double>()));
```

Of course this assumes that you either copy `var2` into a member or do not use it after the constructor exits. If this is not the case, then something is wrong in your design. Perhaps using a raw pointer or a `shared/weak_ptr` is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes this looks much better. Is it safe from memory leaks?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this nicely is to provide two overloads for your constructor:

```
RandomClass(const int16_t var1, const SecondClass& var2)
{
  // ...
}

RandomClass(const int16_t var1)
{
  const SecondClass var2 = *(new SecondClass(*(new std::unordered_map<int16_t, double>()));
}
```

However, you have a much worse problem than how it looks. What you have in that second overload is incredibly horrendous because it results in memory leaks - you need to `delete` everything you `new` but now you've lost any trace of what you `new`ed.  You would simply do this:

```
RandomClass(const int16_t var1)
{
  const SecondClass var2{std::unordered_map<int16_t, double>()};
}
```

Don't use `new` unless you have to - prefer automatic storage duration.